# class+element over-riding class+class

Tags: css, css-specificity

OK I have the following code:

```
<div class="something">
    <div class="something-else">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I try to style it, a CSS rule in another style sheet won't let me do so. The other style sheet has something like:

```
.something h2 {
    color:green;
}
```

I'm trying to override it with:

```
.something .something-else {
    color:red;
}
```

Is the first rule more specific? Because I thought that two classes would win in this situation.

Comment: They are applied to different elements, so there is nothing about overriding here.

Comment: [More reading](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and [more reading from a more recent article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/). Easy ways to calculate specificity.

Answer (score 0):

2 classes + h2 will work for you

you have to select h2 in this case